# Using Tab Bar Controller and Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

[image]

I want to navigate between view controllers as it is shown. I do not want to use segues.

When I try to navigate form `FirstViewController` to `SecondViewController` by clicking a button:

```
 let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondViewController") as! SecondViewController

 self.presentViewController(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I get:

> Warning: Attempt to present SecondViewController on FirstViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Any ideas how to insert Navigation Controllers in-between?

**Edit:** It is `TabBarController` not `TabViewController` on the figure.

I navigate from First Scene's controller named "A-Controller" to First View Controller with :

```
@IBAction func navigateToFirstViewController(sender: AnyObject) {
    let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("firstViewController") as! FirstViewController
    self.presentViewController(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

It is not shown on the figure.

Comment: What kind of controller is handling "First Scene" and its buttons?  What does the code do to present "First View Controller"?

Comment: I did not include First Scene's controller on the figure. Lets's say it is A-controller, then within that controller i use a button to switch to firstViewController @PhillipMills

Comment: Please update your question with the code that implements "switch to firstViewController".  The error message suggests that's there's something unusual in how FirstViewController's view is being used.

Comment: Ok, it is updated now. @PhillipMills

Answer (score 0):

If you try to present modal view over TabBarController, then :

```
let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondViewController") as! UIViewController
self.tabBarController.presentViewController(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: Attempt to present SecondViewController on FirstViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Turns out this error meant I have to do the navigation from First View  to Second View after my First View appears and is ready.

Putting the navigation lines inside viewDidAppear() function solved the issue.